# segmentation fault in files operation in C

Tags: c, file, gcc, segmentation-fault

I am trying to remove extra spaces and newlines from a file using dynaminc memory allocation but I get memory segmentation fault.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
 FILE*fp;
 char ch;
 char *p;
 int i=0,size;
 if((fp = fopen(argv[1],"r"))==NULL) 
   {
    printf("Couldnt open file\n");
    return;
   }

 fseek(fp,0,2);
 size=ftell(fp);


 p = calloc(1,size+1);
 rewind(fp);
 while((p[i] = fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
 {
   i++;
 }
 p[i]=EOF;

 fclose(fp);

 for ( i=0; p[i]!=EOF; i++)
 {
  if (p[i] == ' ' && p[i+1] == ' ')
   {
     memmove(p+i,p+i+1,strlen(p+i+1));
     i--;
   }
  if (p[i] == '\n' && p[i+1] == '\n')
   {
     memmove(p+i,p+i+1,strlen(p+i+1));
     i--;
   }
 } //all extra spaces and newlines deleted..

fp = fopen("modified","w");
if (fp==NULL)
{
 printf("coudlnt create\n");
 return;
}

i=0; 

while((fputc(p[i],fp))!=EOF)
 {
    i++;
 }
   fclose(fp);
 }
```

I get segmentation fault(core dumped) for the above program and if I modify the memmove instruction with strlen(p+i+2) then it doesnt give segmentation fault but gets stuck in some sort of infinite loop.Please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: (1) Why don't you use the proper define values for seek, such as `SEEK_END`: `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END)`? (2) Your `memmove` lines look very suspicious. How do you know when `strlen` is going to see a null character for the end of string and not return a length large enough to overrun your file buffer? (3) the `EOF` value is an integer, so if your file has an `FF` in it, it will be seen as an EOF, possibly unintentionally? Is this an ASCII file or binary?

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see where the error occurs, and with which data?

Comment: the file read is an ASCII file

Comment: If you want me to read this question, please use consistent indention and coding style.

Comment: @Bartlomiej: I am sorry I am a novice in C and dont know how to debug.

Comment: Why do you even allocate memory? Why not reading the file and output it to somewhere else while ignoring extra white spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file-reading is broken; `EOF` is not a character so you cannot compare a character against it and get the proper result.

Read the entire file instead, using `fread()`. Note that it might return a shorter length and need to be looped anyway.

Also stop using `strlen()`; you *know* the length from when you allocated the buffer and read the file in, so it's extremely wasteful in terms of performance to use `strlen()` all the time like you do.

Answer (score 1):

Do not compare char with EOF, which is int.

The whole idea with memmove is error prone, why not check bytes when you are reading it:

```
int b;  // should be int

while ((b = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    char c = (char)b;
    if (p[i] == ' ' &&  c== ' ')  // the same for '\n'
       continue;
    p[++i] = c;
}
```

No need in any memmove at all.